# why is the internal file of my android app doubling in size when adding an item to an Arraylist?

Tags: android, serializable, internal-storage, android-internal-storage

Situation: I have an android application. In this android application I have an internal file containing a "User" class (see code below) this user class has an array-list comprised of spendings, of the "Spending"  class, comprised of several different basic attributes.

Problem: When I get this user from the internal file, add a "Spending" Object to the array-list of the User, then re-save this user (delete file and recreate) it doubles in size the Spendings array-list. 
I even observed it by looking at the files themselves and can see clearly that the entire array-list is doubled every time a spending is added. the user does not seem to be duplicated.
I tried the same process only without adding the spending and it saves just fine without duplication.

the User class:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private int id_utilisateur;
    private String mail;
    private String motDePasse;
    private ArrayList<Spending> mySpendings;

    public Utilisateur(int id_utilisateur, String mail, String motDePasse) {
        this.id_utilisateur = id_utilisateur;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.motDePasse = motDePasse;
        this.mySpendings= new ArrayList<>();
    }

    //Getters and Setters of all attributes here//

    public void addSpending(Spending mySpending) {
        mySpendings.add(mySpending);
    }

}
```

My Spending class :

```
public class Spendingimplements Serializable {

private Integer idSpending;
private Date dateSpending;
private double montant;
private String pieceJoint;
private Magasin magasin;
private String domaine;
private Date garantieDebut;
private Date garantieFin;
private User user;

public Spending(Integer idSpending, Date dateSpending, double montant, User user, String domaine, Magasin magasin, String pieceJoint, Date garantieDebut, Date garantieFin) {
    this.idSpending= idSpending;
    this.dateSpending= dateSpending;
    this.montant = montant;
    this.user= user;
    this.domaine = domaine;
    this.magasin = magasin;
    this.pieceJoint = pieceJoint;
    this.garantieDebut = garantieDebut;
    this.garantieFin = garantieFin;
}

public Spending(Integer idSpending, Date dateSpending, double montant, User user, String domaine, Magasin magasin, String pieceJoint) {
    this.idSpending= idSpending;
    this.dateSpending= dateSpending;
    this.montant = montant;
    this.user= user;
    this.domaine = domaine;
    this.magasin = magasin;
    this.pieceJoint = pieceJoint;
    this.garantieDebut = null;
    this.garantieFin = null;
}

//geters and setters here//
```

}

My class StorageHelper:

```
public final class StorageHelper {

    public StorageHelper() {}

    public static void storeObject(Context context, Object object) {

        try {
            File dir = context.getFilesDir();
            File file = new File(dir, "UserData.data");
            file.delete();

            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("UserData.data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            os.writeObject(object);
            os.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("userFile", "Error: Failed to save User into internal storage - \n" + e.toString());
        }

    }

    public static User getUser(Context context) {
        User mainUser = null;

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput("UserData.data");
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            mainUser = (User) is.readObject();

            is.close();
            fis.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("userFile", "Error: loading from the internal storage failed - \n" + e.toString());
        } finally {
            return mainUser;
        }

    }
}
```

MainActivity :

```
StorageHelper storageHelper;
User mainUser = storageHelper.getUser(this.getBaseContext());
mainUser.addSpending(mySpending);
storageHelper.storeObject(this.getBaseContext(), mainUser);
```

Comment: Could you add Spending class code?

Comment: will do now. one moment please.

Comment: It's a reference of User class inside Spending class, check it, maybe is because of this.

Comment: no sorry, i forgot to change that. as you might have notices i translated the relevant attributes and or classes to make it understandable to you. the original program is in french unfortunately. i edited it now.